# Why "rails server -e production" makes it "No route matches "/" and stylesheet not loading?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

It is running Rails 3.0.0 or Rails 3.0.5 (using Ruby 1.9.2)

When in development mode

```
rails server
```

then http://localhost:3000 works all fine, and http://localhost:3000/foos will load up a `stylesheet.css`

but when it is

```
rails server -e production
```

then now all of a sudden, http://localhost:3000 gives:

```
No route matches "/"
```

and http://localhost:3000/foos can run, but the `stylesheet.css` is not loaded and opening it in the browser shows:

```
No route matches "/stylesheets/scaffold.css"
```

Is special route needed for production vs development? (or is it for some other reason?)

Comment: Post your `config/routes.rb` and `config/environments/production.rb` please.

Comment: it is just a brand new project...  you can get it by `rails new proj` and then `rails g scaffold foo name:string`

Comment: You haven't modified `config/routes.rb` _at all_?

Comment: nope... basically, it contains all comments, except: `Foo192300::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :foos  end`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to set

```
 config.serve_static_assets = true
```

in `config/environments/production.rb`. It's likely commented out in there already.

By default Rails does not serve static files by itself in production, since full-on web servers like Nginx or Apache, will serve them automatically anyway.

Comment: Yes, this is great!  Just don't forget to change that line back before you push to production .... !