# Rails Production server stylesheet not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

I am using the digital ocean ruby on rails image which has nginx and unicorn. I bundled my project `bundle install` and then did `service unicorn restart` but it doesnt seem to be loading. I had this issue a while ago and solved it using `bundle exec ...` but I cant remember the full command. I saw a few issue similar to this and tried `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` as well as editing the production.rb ([Why "rails server -e production" makes it "No route matches "/" and stylesheet not loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287805/why-rails-server-e-production-makes-it-no-route-matches-and-stylesheet-n)) file but it does not work. I am looking for the solution to do this through the command and not through code.

EDIT: `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` did somewhat work! The problem is that I created an extra css file called main.css which isnt importing, but everything else works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`. `RAILS_ENV=production` specifies the environment in which you run your rake tasks.

Comment: I updated the original post. Could you please check that out? Also the enviroment is set in the unicorn config file. It is currently `UNICORN_OPTS="-D -c $CONFIG_RB -E production"`

Comment: It depends on how you configured your assets pipeline. If you compile it manually, then you need to run this command every time you make modifications to your styles. In order to styles be generated manually for appropriate environment, you should pass environment in `RAILS_ENV` constant. If you configured it so they are compiled automatically on load, then you don't need to run any commands at all.

Comment: I finally figured out the issue. `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` does indeed work but I accidentally did code my site poorly. What happened is that I created a file called nahtnam.css which contained all my css. Basically I had bootstrap and I needed a file that loaded after the bootstrap.css file which would override some bootstrap components. Once you compile everything into one file, it stops working properly. I didnt realize  this until now so I dont know what to do. I cant load it in the application.css because that is before bootstrap.css.

Comment: You can require your stylesheets in `application.css` in the order you want. Read more here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization

Comment: I figured it out. I just moved the fonts folder to the public folder. That made the css start working fine. Thanks for your help.